# Ignite 2.10.0 cache.repalce(K,V,V) return false after upgrade from 2.7

Tags: ignite

After upgrade from ignite version 2.7 to 2.10.0 the operation cache.repalce(K,V,V) return false. but with version 2.7 it was working fine.

No exception is thrown just the operation return false. the class is annotated with @EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
the test was done with no code change just the upgrade.

Thank you for your help. I have been trying to solve this problem for a while but with no luck

```js
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=true, onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public class Emplyoee extends BaseClass implements Serialisable {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      
      @QuerySqlField
      private name
    }
}

@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of="id")
public class BaseClass implements Serialisable {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      
      @QuerySqlField
      private id
    }
}


updateEmpolyee(IgniteCache <Long, T> cache, T oldValue, T newValue, Long key, int maxRetry) {
T cacheValue = cache.get(key);
boolean result = cache.replace(key, cacheValue, newValue);
if (!result && maxRetry 0)
 result = updateEmpolyee(cache, newValue, key, maxRetry )
return result;
}
```

Comment: Could you show your test and your value class?

Comment: @ilya  , thank you for your reply. i have added some sample code.

Comment: Anyway, I do not see the difference in my env. I have the same true on both versions. May be could you attach a simple reproducer, which I can run and see different results on different versions.

Comment: Hello @ilya it will takes me a while to prepare the environment. Is it possible that the equals return false when we try to cache.replace(k, v, v )                                                            if (cache.containsKey(key) && equals(cache.get(key), oldValue)) {
  cache.put(key, newValue);
 return true;
 } else {
  return false;
 } . Because when I used cache.replace(k, v) everything works fine. Is there any other method can i used in place of cache.replace(k, v, v)  . Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a couple of improvements in `#replace(k,v,nv)` method, like [IGNITE-11734](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-11734) and [IGNITE-7072](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-7072).

The most interesting changes are in `#11734` that introduced the following lines:

```
    // here val is stored value, this.val = new value

    if (this.val == null && val == null)
        return true;

    if (this.val == null || val == null)
        return false;
```

I.e. if there were no value for a given key (no record exists) and you are trying to make a value replacement, you will always get `false` starting from 2.8. Though it looks like this is how it worked in 2.7 as well...

Here you might check a complete source code of [CacheEntryPredicateContainsValue#apply](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/internal/processors/cache/CacheEntryPredicateContainsValue.java#L59) method.